# Xor encryption/decryption of a file with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, xor

I need to encrypt / decrypt a file using xor with Python 3, I have a code that works fine in Python 2, but when trying to adapt it to Python 3, gives me some errors that I can't solve.

This code works fine in Python 2.7:

```
from itertools import cycle


def xore(data, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))

with open('inputfile.jpg', 'rb') as encry, open('outputfile.jpg', 'wb') as decry:
    decry.write(xore(encry.read(), 'anykey'))
```

The error when trying to run unchanged in python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask.py", line 8, in <module>
    decry.write(xore(encry.read(), 'anykey'))
  File "ask.py", line 5, in xore
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))
  File "ask.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Please if someone could explain and help me adapt this code to Python 3.

Comment: Try this - `return ''.join(chr(ord(str(a)) ^ ord(str(b))) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))`

Comment: You are opening the file with `b` so `a` is an int each time, `''.join(chr(a ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))`

Comment: If they're already ints, couldn't you just remove the call to `ord`?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is already an `int` so you would need to remove the call to `ord(a)`:

```
def xore(data, key):
    return ''.join(chr(a ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(data, cycle(key)))
```

You will not be able to write the joined string to your outfile without a  `.encode("utf-8")` which will not give you any usable output so not sure what you are actually trying to achieve.

You can see when you index a byte string you get an int in python3:

```
n [1]: s = b"foo"

In [2]: s[0]
Out[2]: 102  # f
```

Where in python2 you get the str/char:

```
In [1]: s = b"foo"
In [2]: s[0]
Out[2]: 'f'
```

iterating or calling next also gives you the integer value:

```
In [12]: it = iter(s)   
In [13]: next(it)
Out[13]: 102
In [14]: for ele in s:
         print(ele)
   ....:     
102
111
111
```

In python2 you would just get each character.  So in your code as you iterate over the bytes objects returned from `encry.read()` you are getting the integer values so `ord(some_int)` obviously fails.

There is a thorough explanation [text-versus-binary-data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data) which explains the differences between python2 and python3 a snippet of which is:

> As part of this dichotomy you also need to be careful about opening files. Unless you have been working on Windows, there is a chance you have not always bothered to add the b mode when opening a binary file (e.g., rb for binary reading). 
>   Under Python 3, binary files and text files are clearly distinct and mutually incompatible; see the io module for details. Therefore, you must make a decision of whether a file will be used for binary access (allowing to read and/or write binary data) or text access (allowing to read and/or write text data). You should also use io.open() for opening files instead of the built-in open() function as the io module is consistent from Python 2 to 3 while the built-in open() function is not (in Python 3 it’s actually io.open()).
>
> The constructors of both str and bytes have different semantics for the same arguments between Python 2 & 3. Passing an integer to bytes in Python 2 will give you the string representation of the integer: `bytes(3) == '3'`. But in Python 3, an integer argument to bytes will give you a bytes object as long as the integer specified, filled with null bytes: `bytes(3) == b'\x00\x00\x00'`. A similar worry is necessary when passing a bytes object to str. In Python 2 you just get the bytes object back: `str(b'3') == b'3'`. But in Python 3 you get the string representation of the bytes object: `str(b'3') == "b'3'"`.
>
> Finally, the indexing of binary data requires careful handling (slicing does not require any special handling). **In Python 2, `b'123'[1] == b'2'` while in Python 3 `b'123'[1] == 50`. Because binary data is simply a collection of binary numbers, Python 3 returns the integer value for the byte you index on. But in Python 2 because bytes == str, indexing returns a one-item slice of bytes.** The six project has a function named six.indexbytes() which will return an integer like in Python 3: six.indexbytes(b'123', 1).